# Падает приложение Android. ANR

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

Я пишу приложение на Android с помощью Xamarin. В приложении есть сервис, работающий в фоне и обращающийся к api. Сервис может работать долго (несколько часов) но в какой-то момент, обычно после часа-двух работы, приложение вместе с сервисом падают. 
Заглянул в logcat, там нашёл вот такие логи

```
06-14 22:23:19.715 21636 14406 I chatty  : uid=10469(apisearch.app) com.google.android.gms:snet expire 4 lines
06-14 22:29:23.484  1370  1486 W BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout of BroadcastRecord{a9b6e57 u-1 android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON} : BroadcastFilter{2c89fd4 u0 ReceiverList{88a5127 21636 apisearch.app/10469/u0 remote:ab777e6}}
06-14 22:29:23.997 21636 21643 I chatty  : uid=10469(apisearch.app) com.google.android.gms:snet expire 6 lines
06-14 22:29:29.544  1370  1486 E ActivityManager: ANR in apisearch.app
06-14 22:29:29.544  1370  1486 E ActivityManager:   5.1% 21636/apisearch.app: 1.6% user + 3.4% kernel / faults: 2368 minor 47 major
06-14 22:29:39.681  1370  1486 W BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout of BroadcastRecord{a9b6e57 u-1 android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON} : BroadcastFilter{15c8096 u0 ReceiverList{6613b1 21636 apisearch.app/10469/u0 remote:1b9e658}}
06-14 22:29:39.757  1370  1486 I ActivityManager: Skipping duplicate ANR: ProcessRecord{216d57d 21636:apisearch.app/u0a469} Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50200010 }
06-14 22:29:45.734   767  2549 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: 156adb9 Application Not Responding: apisearch.app#0
06-14 22:29:59.217  1370  1486 W BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout of BroadcastRecord{c88555d u-1 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} : BroadcastFilter{c3a341a u0 ReceiverList{c12c5 21636 apisearch.app/10469/u0 remote:cd2e53c}}
06-14 22:30:04.496  1370  1486 E ActivityManager: ANR in apisearch.app
06-14 22:30:04.496  1370  1486 E ActivityManager:   3.8% 21636/apisearch.app: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 1972 minor
06-14 22:30:04.506  1370  1487 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity apisearch.app/md567688bd8e9e66faa4b09faba0f3906cb.CommentsActivity
06-14 22:30:04.522  1370  1487 I ActivityManager: Killing 21636:apisearch.app/u0a469 (adj 200): user request after error
06-14 22:30:05.169  1370  3238 I AutoStartManagerService: MIUILOG- Reject RestartService packageName :apisearch.app uid : 10469
06-14 22:30:05.169  1370  1836 I ProcessManager: remove no clear notification:StatusBarNotification(pkg=apisearch.app user=UserHandle{0} id=10000 tag=null key=0|apisearch.app|10000|null|10469: Notification(channel=search service channel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))
06-14 22:30:05.208  2093  2093 I Launcher.ApplicationsMessage: update apisearch.app/ to null
06-14 22:30:05.215  1370  3290 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{e97fff3 u0 apisearch.app/md567688bd8e9e66faa4b09faba0f3906cb.CommentsActivity}
06-14 22:30:05.215  1370  3241 I AutoStartManagerService: MIUILOG- Reject RestartService packageName :apisearch.app uid : 10469
06-14 22:30:05.225  1370  3251 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{b5e3c91 u0 apisearch.app/md567688bd8e9e66faa4b09faba0f3906cb.MainActivity}
06-14 22:30:05.258  1370  1486 W BroadcastQueue: Skipping deliver [foreground] BroadcastRecord{c88555d u-1 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} to ReceiverList{4f2a81d 21636 apisearch.app/10469/u0 remote:37b98f4}: process gone or crashing
06-14 22:30:05.296  1370  3241 W BroadcastQueue: Skipping deliver [foreground] BroadcastRecord{c88555d u-1 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} to ReceiverList{6613b1 21636 apisearch.app/10469/u0 remote:1b9e658}: process gone or crashing
```

Вижу что в логах фигурирует ANR (Apllication Not Responding), и незадолго до падения я действительно получаю уведомление что оно не отвечает. Но я никак не могу понять с чем это связано и как эту проблему решить. Может кто в курсе почему это происходит?

Comment: ANR происходит когда в главном потоке выполняется блокирующая операция более 5с. Таким образом, проблема может быть в том, что вы делаете долгий запрос в БД или в сеть на основном потоке.

Comment: Покажите, как выглядит сервис и как вы его запускаете